# Circleci : Cannot find a definition for job named publish-latest

Tags: yaml, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

```
  version: 2.1
  executors:
    docker-publisher:
      environment:
        IMAGE_NAME: mocking-service
      docker:
        - image: circleci/buildpack-deps:stretch
  jobs:
    build:
       executor: docker-publisher
       steps:
         - checkout
         - setup_remote_docker
         - run:
            name: Build Docker image
            command: |
              docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:latest .
         - run:
            name: Archive Docker image
            command: docker save -o mocking.tar $IMAGE_NAME
         - persist_to_workspace:
              root: .
              paths:
                - ./mocking.tar
  publish-latest:
      executor: docker-publisher
      steps:
        - attach_workspace:
            at: /tmp/workspace
        - setup_remote_docker
        - run:
            name: Load archived Docker image
            command: docker load -i /tmp/workspace/mocking.tar
        - run:
            name: Publish Docker Image to Docker Hub
            command: |
                  echo "$DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME" --password-stdin
                  docker push docker.kfz42.de/v2/java/mocking-service/$IMAGE_NAME:latest .
  workflows:
    version: 2
    build-master:
      jobs:
        - build:
            filters:
             branches:
               only: master
        - publish-latest:
            requires:
              - build
            filters:
              branches:
                only: master
```

Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong here?
I get the following error when I try to run this yaml file via circleci

> !/bin/sh -eo pipefail Error calling workflow: 'build-master' Cannot
>   find a definition for job named publish-latest
>
> Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message
>   above. Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect. false

Comment: circleci yaml files have strict indentation.  annoyingly, all the "online yaml checkers" don't care about indentation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your indentation is off. publish-latest should be should be indented like other defined jobs.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by marxmacher, it looks like an indentation error. If you have the [CircleCi CLI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/), you can run `circleci config validate` command, which will show you any issues within your config file.

Comment: indeed, just brew install circleci on a mac for example and away you go.